# Sitecore read access to get items, Sitecore 8.2u2

Tags: security

Do I need Read access to an item if I need codebehind to get that item programatically?

`Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ID)` will return null if I don't put read access on the item.

My code worked before upgrade from sitecore 7.2 to 8.2.

Can anyone confirm that you need read access to the item you want to get since a release after 7.2?

If not, any idea why it worked on Sitecore 7.2?

Comment: Yes, you need read access to use `GetItem` method. It may be set directly or inherited from one of the ancestors. It works exactly the same in 7.2. Maybe you lost some access rights configuration during upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calls through the Sitecore API will take the security settings into account so you'll need to have read access to the item.

You can get around this by using the `SecurityDisabler`

```
using(Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler()){
  Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ID)
  ...
}
```